# Qtranslate + Advanced Custom Fields: how to have a multilanguage wysiwyg editor?

Tags: multi-language, wysiwyg, plugin-qtranslate, advanced-custom-fields

This is my setup:

- Wordpress: 3.4.2
- qTranslate: 2.5.32
- Advanced Custom Field: 3.5.1
- i've also installed qTranslate extension: 1.1.1 but I don't know how/if it works...

How can I have a multilanguage WYSIWYG custom field edit area with tabs for each language as the main text editor?

Thanks!
Stefano

Comment: qTranslate extension? Can you provide the link? For what I know of qT and ACF, I'd say doing what you want would be a **huge** task...

Comment: qTranslate extension is this one http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate-extended/

Answer (score 0):

Tip 1: do not use qtranslate. I've used for years and now I can say that never been money better spent than those for [WPML](http://wpml.org), specially if compared to the work needed to solve problems qT brings.
Also consider that WPML is compatible with a huge number of plugins and themes, in years I used qTranslate never found a theme or a plugin compatible with it.

Tip 2: Regardless of which plugin you use, qT or WPML, to do what you want, require to write an entire and complex plugin.

A workaroud is to use **different fields for different languages**.

E.g. have the field 'size' for english and field 'taglia' for italian, and so on. Than in template file retrieve current language and print right field using a `switch` statement.

Following code is just an example

```
function get_localized_size($postid) {
    if ( ! intval($postid) ) {
      global $post;
      if ( empty($post) || ! is_object($post) || ! isset($post->ID) ) return;
      $postid = $post->ID;
    }
    $currlang = qtrans_getLanguage() ? : 'en'; // <-- qtranslate
    // $currlang = defined('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE') ? ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE : 'en'; // <-- WPML
    switch ( strtolower($currlang) ) {
      case 'es' :
        $field = 'tamano';
        break;
      case 'it' :
        $field = 'taglia';
        break;
      case 'fr' :
        $field = 'taille';
        break;
      case 'en' :
      default :
        $field = 'size';
        break;
    }
    $size = get_post_meta($postid,  $field, true);
    return sprintf( __('The size is: %s', YOURTEXTDOMAIN ), $size );
}
```

Than in the loop:

```
...
the_post();
...
echo get_localized_size(); // pass post ID as argument when out of the loop
...
```